# Allow users to only access certain tables in my content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite

I'm planning the database for my app.

I would like to allow others to use my data. However, I only want them to access a couple tables. Is it possible to only allow other apps to access certain tables?

Having all my db code in one place (content provider) just seems like a good idea, rather than having to split it up.

What would be considered best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Android Manifest file you should for your content provider tag set an attribute `grandUriPermissions` to `false`. Thus, you will protect all data of your content provider from access. After that inside `<provider> </provider>` you should add tag `<grant-uri-permission>`. About its attribute you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/grant-uri-permission-element.html). (Your case, I guess, is pathPrefix attribute)

Comment: Ah. This looks interesting. Do these permissions only affect other apps or will I also be under scrutiny when I (my app) require access.

Comment: I do not know - never tested this approach. I guess your application will not hurt. But this need to be tested.