# Several Android Content Providers on one database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contentprovider

It is in general possible to have more than one content provider for only one database?

I have the following situation / wish:

1. I have one app with database that stores "master data" (such as project definitions and preferences) and "live data" (such as working time for this projects).
2. I have internal content provider to read and write data.

Now I want two more content provider for external use.

1. One for the access to "master data" (must have special permissions for read and write)
2. One for the access to "live data" (must have special permissions for read and write, but different to the firs one).

Is it possible? And how?

I tried to implement the different providers, but I get al lot of "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/package/databases/db.db (conn# 0) already closed".

I use only the content provider for the database access. Loader for list of data (Spinner, ListViews) and direct content provider access for single rows.

**Edit:**

**This solution does work (`FAKE_PERMISSION`)!**

```
<provider android:name=".provider.MyContentProvider"
    android:authorities="my.package.provider"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="FAKE_PERMISSION" >
    <path-permission
        android:pathPrefix="/master_data"
        android:readPermission="my.package.PERMISSION_READ_MASTER_DATA"
        android:writePermission="my.package.PERMISSION_WRITE_MASTER_DATA" />
    <path-permission
        android:pathPrefix="/live_data"
        android:readPermission="my.package.PERMISSION_READ_LIVE_DATA"
        android:writePermission="my.package.PERMISSION_WRITE_LIVE_DATA" />
</provider>
```

**Without global provider permission does NOT work!** Both paths are accessible from external app without `uses-permission`.

```
<provider android:name=".provider.MyContentProvider"
    android:authorities="my.package.provider"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
    <path-permission
        android:pathPrefix="/master_data"
        android:readPermission="my.package.PERMISSION_READ_MASTER_DATA"
        android:writePermission="my.package.PERMISSION_WRITE_MASTER_DATA" />
    <path-permission
        android:pathPrefix="/live_data"
        android:readPermission="my.package.PERMISSION_READ_LIVE_DATA"
        android:writePermission="my.package.PERMISSION_WRITE_LIVE_DATA" />
</provider>
```

Comment: Maybe in your case you can realize one ContentProvider and install permissions to different URI of this ContentProvider (read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417680/allow-users-to-only-access-certain-tables-in-my-content-provider/11419725#11419725) question and my answer). Hope this helps you!

Comment: I tried this so far with two permission for `live` and `master` paths. It seems that I have to have a global permission for the content provider to activate the path specialized permission. Without the global permission I can read and write all data without the permission.